# How to get only the value from an input using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a code using beautiful soup that works perfectly to get an element by its id (I have to get by the id).
But my output is the following:

```
[<td id="testebia"><input type="text" value="123599"/></td>]
```

I could only reduce to this:

```
<input type="text" value="123599"/>
```

using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = ('https://naughty-poincare-e28558.netlify.app/')

r = requests.get(url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

number = soup.select("#testebia")

for lista_dados  in number:
  print(lista_dados.next_element)
```

What can I do to get only the value? In this case 123599

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `<input>` and get the `value=` attribute:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://naughty-poincare-e28558.netlify.app/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

val = soup.select_one("#testebia > input")["value"]
print(val)
```

Prints:

```
123599
```

---

Or using your code:

```py
for n in soup.select("#testebia"):
    print(n.find("input")["value"])
```

Comment: Oh, my god!! Thank you so much! You saved my life lol